# How can I configure Auto Scaling with boto using scaling policies and metrics?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto, autoscaling

I'm trying to configure [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) using scaling policies and metric alarms rather than triggers now that they are being deprecated. I have successfully created a launch configuration and a Auto Scaling group, but am having trouble creating scaling policies and metric alarms. If anyone could provide some links to some examples, or provide some of there own, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

A concise but well documented code example from active boto committer [Liam Friel](https://github.com/liamf) is his gist that [Demonstrates using patched boto to create an autoscaling group of servers, scaled up/down by CPU Utilisation](https://gist.github.com/958833).

A more elaborate and less code centric writeup on the subject matter is WallOfFire's tutorial [Setting up Queue-size-based auto scaling groups in AWS](http://ruben.orduz.info/2011/12/setting-up-queue-size-based-auto.html), which apparently addresses current shortcomings within the AWS documentation as well.

In case none of these enable you to overcome your hurdles, you should amend your question with more details regarding the trouble you have.

Good luck!

Comment: Does any have a response for boto3?